# C# - Class not registered - creating a Excel spreadsheet with Macros using VBIDE

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, interop

Using VS2010, I cannot use the VBIDE interop DLL. Could someone please see if they can reproduce on their PC - code straight out of http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303872

1. Create winform app in C#.
2. Reference these 2 DLLs:
   `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`
3. In Form_load put this code:

---

```
//Using statments
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;    
using VBIDE = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;
using System.Reflection;

Excel.Application excelApp = null;
Excel._Workbook excelWorkbook;
Excel._Worksheet excelSheet;
excelApp = new Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
excelWorkbook = (Excel._Workbook)(excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
excelSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
VBIDE.VBComponent oModule = new VBIDE.VBComponent();  //<--BAM throws an error
```

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {BE39F3DA-1B13-11D0-887F-00A0C90F2744} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: woops had the code wrong from the KB Article... now I get "Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```
VBIDE.VBComponent oModule;

oModule = excelWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
```